# Perform a simulated button press when key is stroked in Tkinter GUI

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm building a simple calculator GUI, I was able to bind a keystroke to button clicks and the code runs well.

What I'm trying to do now is to simulate a button click while the right key was stroked, meaning that for example let say the key '5' was pressed on the keyboard I would like the button '5' to look like it was pressed

My attempts so far included using a dummy function that is calling 2 other functions that should do exactly what I described but it not working:

```
def numeric_keystroke_action(self, event):
    k = find_key_from_value(calculator_button_text, event.char)
    self.simulate_button_press(k)
    self.click(event.char, False)
    self.simulate_button_idle(k)

def simulate_button_press(self, key):
    self.buttons[key].configure(style='pressed_style.TButton')

def simulate_button_idle(self, key):
    self.buttons[key].configure(style='idle_style.TButton')
```

My other attempt is to use the `add="+"` in `bind()` but it didn't work either, it called only the first binding and the key was stuck on "stroke" mode, meaning it just call the first binding function and not the second one:

```
...
    self.master.bind(k, lambda event: self.numeric_keystroke_action(event))
    self.master.bind(k, lambda event: self.simulate_button_idle(key), add="+")
...

def numeric_keystroke_action(self, event):
    k = find_key_from_value(calculator_button_text, event.char)
    self.simulate_button_press(k)
    self.click(event.char, False)
    #self.simulate_button_idle(k)

def simulate_button_press(self, key):
    self.buttons[key].configure(style='pressed_style.TButton')

def simulate_button_idle(self, key):
    self.buttons[key].configure(style='idle_style.TButton')
```

Would appreciate some help

Comment: If you downvote, just leave a comment explaining why. I'm always eager to learn and improve!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `btn.invoke()` to simulate a click on the button:

```
import tkinter as tk

def _key_(k):
    print(k)
    btn.invoke()

def _5():
    print(5)

root = tk.Tk()
btn = tk.Button(root, text='_____5_____', command=_5)
btn.pack()

root.bind('5', _key_)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of immediately calling `simulate_button_idle`, use `after` to call it after a short delay:

```
def numeric_keystroke_action(self, event):
    k = find_key_from_value(calculator_button_text, event.char)
    self.simulate_button_press(k)
    self.after(250, self.simulate_button_idle, k)
    self.click(event.char, False)
```

Comment: Thanks, what is the method `after`? I tried to use the same logic and delay the execution of `self.simulate_button_idle` using `time.sleep()` but it didn't work; also would appreciate an upvote

Comment: `after` is a common widget method just like `configure`, `pack`, etc. It schedules code to run after a delay. `sleep` won't work because that's exactly what it does: it puts the whole UI to sleep. `after` lets the event loop continue running, and then the function will be executed as soon after the delay as possible. It is the event loop that causes the UI to update when you reconfigure the widget. If the UI is sleeping, the window can be refreshed to show the new configuration.